# Dealing with spaces in Flask url creation

Tags: python, flask

In a flask app I'm working on, I use U.S. state names as part of the url structure. State names are pulled from a python dictionary that links state abbreviations with their respective proper name, e.g.

```
state_dict = {"Alabama" : "AL", "Alaska" : "AK",...
```

This is fine when the state name has no spaces. e.g. `http://example.com/Alabama/` However, when the state in question has a space in it, it forms a poor url. e.g. `http://example.com/North%20Dakota/`

I currently get around this by being careful when I create urls using the state names to use something like `state=state.replace(' ', '_')` as an argument in `url_for()`. However, it's cumbersome and seems crude.

**How can I better use state names as part of the url without having to manually modify them each time?** Extra points if the solution can also be used to change upper case letters to lowercase.

I've considered modifying the state dict to be url friendly e.g. `north_dakota` instead of `North Dakota` however, the dict is also used when creating text to display to users, and readability counts.

Thanks very much for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common pattern for python would be to use a pair of dictionaries for the forward / reverse lookup to go from and to your friendly dictionary. On a side note, the term commonly used for such a "url-friendly" representation of a string value is "slug".

```
# state_slugs lets you lookup either state name or code => its slug
state_slugs = {}
# states_from_slugs lets you lookup the slug => the state name
states_from_slugs = {}

for state_name, state_code in state_dict.items():
    slug = state_name.lower().replace(' ', '_')
    state_slugs[state_name] = slug
    state_slugs[state_code] = slug
    states_from_slugs[slug] = state_name
```

You would put this somewhere it's run only once, like possibly at module-level, or soon after your `state_dict` has been created.

Then accessing either `state_slugs['NC']` or `state_slugs['North Carolina']` will both work to return "north_carolina"  and accessing `states_from_slugs['north_carolina']` will return 'North Carolina' for the reverse lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered generating a second dictionary to represent your url-friendly state-names?  And just so you don't have to worry about adding the 51st state (whenever that happens) to two dictionaries, you can do this easily at runtime:

```
state_dictionary = {'South Carolina': 'SC', 'North Carolina': 'NC'}
url_friendly = {k.lower().replace(' ', '_'): v
                for k, v in state_dictionary.iteritems()}
```

or, for pre-2.7 python:

```
url_friendly = dict((k.lower().replace(' ', '_'), v)
                for k, v in state_dictionary.iteritems())
```

produces something like this:

```
{'south_carolina': 'SC', 'north_carolina': 'NC'}
```