# Storing and Accessing U.S. State Attributes in Python / Flask

Tags: python, flask

## Question:

How best* can I store and access fixed U.S. State attributes in my python program?

`*` the most reasonable combination of clear, maintainable, quick and idiomatic

### Background info:

I'm creating a python/flask app that regularly accesses U.S. State attributes for various displays and sorting. An example of the attributes:

State: South Carolina

- Proper Name: `South Carolina`
- Abbreviation: `SC`
- url friendly slug: `south_carolina`
- Region: `southeast`

Currently, I'm storing some of this information in dictionaries ([SO question regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372221/dealing-with-spaces-in-flask-url-creation)). However, it seem more unwieldy as more attributes are added.

---

### Some options I've considered

- Adding more dictionaries

  - Seems clumsy
- Use a database

  - I'm new to databases. I'm happy to learn, but I'm not clear this is the best approach. Also, I'm concerned this would be overkill.
- Add a `State` Class

  - Seems a little inelegant to create 50 `State` objects just to query a few attributes.

Thanks very much for your time.

Edit: Added explanation of what best means.

Comment: @Blender Fair question. Best = What is the most reasonable combination of clear, maintainable, quick and idiomatic

Comment: Do you need to be able to look up a state by any of these attributes or will only be looking them up with one of them (i.e. you'll always be looking up states by abbreviation)?

Comment: @SeanVieira It's not required, but would be very, very nice. Good point, thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a database to solve this problem. I considered a bunch of options and it seems to be the most reasonable in terms of effort, complexity and long-term maintenance.

Trying to make some other solution solve my problem here would really only be a crude recreation of database functionality anyhow e.g. dictionaries on dictionaries on dictionaries...

For those wondering, on this particular [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) app I went with [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) on top of a [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/) database.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this [config module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/config/0.3.7). It would allow you to define all of your state attributes in one place and would be more simple and efficient than accessing them through a database.

Comment: Thanks much for your response. However, I ended up going with a database to solve this problem. I guess that means I don't mark this as the answer? Thanks anyhow.